# Minimum absolute difference after diving number from 1 to n into two groups

Tags: number-theory, algorithms

I am trying to solve an algorithmic problem mentioned at https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/divide-1-n-two-groups-minimum-sum-difference/.
In the solution it says "We can always divide sum of n integers in two groups such that their absolute difference of their sum is 0 or 1. So sum of group at most differ by 1".I am struggling to prove this statement.Can someone please help in proving this statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that if you have a division for $1$ to $n$, then you get another division for $1$ to $n + 4$, by adding $n + 1$ and $n + 4$ to one side, $n + 2$ and $n + 3$ to the other side.

Hence it suffices to consider the case of $n = 1, 2, 3, 4$. These are super easy.

Comment: make sense.thanks a lot.